# Mounting remote CIFs share using hostname

Tags: windows, debian, cifs

I'm trying to mount a remote Windows share on a VPS using the following command:

`sudo mount -t CIFS //cifs.example.com/sharename -o username=blah`

But this throws a `wrong FS type` error.  If I substitute `cifs.example.com` with my IP address, then it mounts fine.

How can I get around this issue?

Comment: I presume an `nslookup` on `cifs.example.com` returns the same IP address?

Comment: It does, yeah.  I think my VPS looks at `cifs.example.com` and jut decides it's a local hostname, and gives up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FINALLY.

Installed `cifs-utils` for starters, which didn't resolve the issue but has certainly paved the way.  Once I specified `vers=3.0`, the drive mounted without issue.